# Where does the terminology "fake/false elliptic curve" come from?

Tags: terminology, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

In describing, say, the moduli of Shimura curves, people often refer to "*fake*" or "*false elliptic curves*" ("les fausses courbes elliptiques"), which are abelian surfaces whose endomorphism ring is an order of quaternion algebra with center $\textbf{Q}$.

Where does this terminology come from? (Deligne-Rapoport attributes this terminology to Serre, but I cannot seem to find a paper that gives an explanation for the term.) And why should one distinguish this specific case as a "false elliptic curve" and not, say, some other abelian variety with some special kind of endomorphism ring?

Comment: Presumably the motivation is that one wants to present the moduli-space interpretation of Shimura curves in such a way as to make it sound as much as possible like modular curves.